# "Assuming that H0 or Ha is true"

Tags: statistical-significance

The common way of indicating type 1, type 2 errors or power is to specify a hypothetical situation in which either there is or there is not an effect in the population. E.g., Given that there is an effect in the population this test has 80 % power to detect the effect. For discrete outcomes this makes sense, detecting whether you are looking at a circle or a square and given the condition of your eyes (measurement error) you will make a mistake 5 % of the time (detect a circle while in fact it is a square).

However, in continuous measures (e.g. Reaction time), the same statement loses value. Assuming that there is an RT difference is meaningless if not applying another criterium (when is the difference big enough to say there is an effect). Is the statement: assuming that Ho is true possible for these situations?

Is the assumption only hypothetical and therefore relatively meaningless or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. This is undeniably amongst the most important critic of Null Hypothesis Statistical Testing. That's why reporting effect size and confidence interval is important. Even if it does not fully solve the problem of publication bias, it allows the reader to be more aware of the strength of the result published.

According to [this abstract](http://epm.sagepub.com/content/62/5/749.short), the 5th manual of APA strongly highlighted the importance of these complementary practices (reporting effect size + confidence intervals).

> The fifth edition of the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association (APA) draws on recommendations for improving statistical practices made by the APA Task Force on Statistical Inference (TFSI). The manual now acknowledges the controversy over null hypothesis significance testing (NHST) and includes both a stronger recommendation to report effect sizes and a new recommendation to report confidence intervals [..]

Comment: Thanks! I guess the 'new statistics' improves bits although it shifts the decision criteria to new measurements (which CI implies there is an effect, which effect size implies there is an effect  etc.)